# Laravel controller is giving different answer to route test

Tags: laravel, mockery

I'm building some unit tests for controllers with Laravel 4 and Mockery.

I've been testing by both calling controller methods directly (to unit test the method in isolation), and calling the method via routes (to focus on the response), but I'm getting different answers based on whether I call the controller vs go via the route.

Here's my resourceful Controller:

```
class UserController extends \BaseController {

    protected $user;
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    // Get and delete user
    $this->getUser($id);
    $this->user->delete();

    return $this->ok();             // This is just a json response::json
}

/**
 * Attempts to find the user requested 
 * 
 * @param  $id The ID they are trying to find
 */
private function getUser($id) 
{
    // Attempt to find the user
    $this->user = $this->user->find($id);

    // Throw exception if we can't find it
    if(is_null($this->user)) throw new ResourceNotFoundException('User '.$id.' not found'); 

    return;
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController', array('only' => array('index', 'store','show','update','destroy')));
```

And here are my tests:

```
use Way\Tests\Factory;

class UserControllerUnitTest extends TestCase {

public function setUp() 
{
    parent::setUp();

    // Fake objects
    $this->fake_user_nonadmin = Factory::user(array('id' => 2, 'admin' => FALSE, 'deleted_at' => null));

    // Mock objects
    $this->mock_user = Mockery::mock('User')->makePartial();  

    // Make the controller
    $this->controller = new UserController($this->mock_user);
}
public function tearDown()
{
    Mockery::close();
}

protected function prepDestroyOk($id) 
{
    $this->mock_user
         ->shouldReceive('find')
         ->once()
         ->with($id)
         ->andReturn($this->mock_user);

    $this->mock_user
         ->shouldReceive('delete')
         ->once()
         ->andReturn('foo');
}
public function testDestroyOk() 
{
    $id = $this->fake_user_nonadmin->id;
    $this->prepDestroyOk($id);

    $this->controller->destroy($id);
}       
public function testDestroyOkRoute() 
{
    $id = $this->fake_user_nonadmin->id;
    $this->prepDestroyOk($id);

    $response = $this->client->request('DELETE', 'users/'.$id);
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertEquals(get_class($response), "Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse");
}
```

You see I'm testing direct controller access in `testDestroyOk()`, vs calling the same method via routes.php for `testDestroyOkRoute()`. Both test cases are set up using the common `prepDestroyOk()` method to ensure they are consistent.

Yet `testDestroyOk()` passes and `testDestroyOkRoute()` fails as it throws a ResourceNotFoundException from `getUser()` method in my controller.

Any ideas why accessing the controller works but going via routes is somehow treated differently?

Comment: If you have an **answer**, please post it **as** an answer. Questions belong at the top, in the question box, answers belong down below, as answers. And don't edit `solved` into the title - we know your question has been adequately dealt with when you accept an answer. Answering one's own questions is explicitly allowed as part of the SO culture.

Comment: I thought that posting some sort of solution would help the community as a whole -- better than simply leaving it unanswered. Thanks for the pointers though. Have corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realised that I was forgetting to bind the mock User object into the IoC container, which is the reason why the test was failing. When calling the controller directly, the mock User object was part of the test class. When calling through a route, Laravel was resolving a (non-mock) User object instead which caused it to fail.

Updating the test to the following makes it pass as expected:

```
public function testDestroyOkRoute() 
{
    $id = $this->fake_user_nonadmin->id;
    $this->prepDestroyOk($id);
    $this->app->instance('User',$this->mock_user);   // <= I was forgetting this

    $response = $this->call('DELETE', 'users/'.$id);
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertEquals(get_class($response), "Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse");  
}
```